# Is it possible to override the method used to call Django's admin delete confirmation page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

On Django's admin pages, I'd like to perform an action when the administrator clicks the Delete button for an object.  In other words, I'd like to execute some code prior to arriving on the "Are you sure?" delete confirmation page.

I realize I could override the template page for this object, but I was hoping for something easier (i.e., override a method on the model or the form).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why aren't you creating a Form for this?

Comment: Why should he? Delete is a function of the admin, not a form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override `ModelAdmin.delete_view()` method, like:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        # if request.POST is set, the user already confirmed deletion
        if not request.POST:
            perform_my_action()
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

Comment: Does this solution works also for multi-delete in django admin, when several object are deleted in one operation?

Answer (score 3):

We can use django.shortcuts.redirect to interrupt deletion, like this:

```
def check_del(self, object_id):
    produkt = Produkt.objects.get(id = object_id)
    if produkt.typsklepu_set.all():
        return False
    else:
        return True

def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    # if request.POST is set, the user already confirmed deletion
    if not request.POST and self.check_del(object_id):
        return super(ProduktAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
    elif request.POST:
        return super(ProduktAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
    else:
        msg = u'Can not delete this object.'
        messages.error(request, msg)
        return redirect('..')
```